# File custom field type in jBPM6

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jbpm

Actually, I am trying to add a file field type to the task form in which the user will be able to upload a file in the task form.

I do the corresponding procedure:

1) ant  clean.demo

2) add "File Input": new org.jbpm.formModeler.core.fieldTypes.file.FileCustomType() tp the jBPM-installer/conf/META-INF/ CustomWorkItemHandlers.conf

3) add cutomFieldType.jar (which include the build of following    https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-form-modeler/tree/master/jbpm-form-modeler-sample-custom-types/jbpm-form-modeler-custom-file-type. )  to the WEB/lib

4) ant install.demo

5) ant start.demo

BUT unfortunately I faced with deployment failed
here is the error:

```
2015-01-23 11:52:35,578 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name fdch resolves to beans: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.jbpm.formModeler.fieldTypes.document.handling.FileDownloadHandler] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jbpm.formModeler.core.fieldTypes.file.FileDownloadHandler] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$5.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$5.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:130)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    ... 3 more
```

Could you help me if I am missing something???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occure because there two bean with the same name (fdch )in two different jar

(jbpm-form-modeler-custom-file-type.jar) and your jar (cutomFieldType.jar)

you need to change the name of bean for this class to be another name for example (@Named("mybean"))

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-form-modeler/blob/master/jbpm-form-modeler-sample-custom-types/jbpm-form-modeler-custom-file-type/src/main/java/org/jbpm/formModeler/core/fieldTypes/file/FileDownloadHandler.java

or  you can remove the jbpm-form-modeler-custom-file-type.jar from web-inf\ib

Comment: Thx a lot.. Actually I understood yesterday and just deleted one of the beans from the lib.. Thx a lot for your answer :-)